# How exactly can you add external JS in Gantry Joomla websites?

Tags: javascript, jquery, joomla

I seem to be getting confused about something here, as I'm sure I'm reading correctly, but something just isn't work right.

I've been passed a Gantry based website running on Joomla, and have been asked to make some changes. One of which, is by including a JS file, and then a simple call to it.

From reading the Gantry docs, I'm doing this in the following way by adding this to the Gantry template's index.php file:

```
$gantry->addScript('jquery.atooltip.min.js');
$gantry->addScript('init.js');
```

Logically, this seems as though the plugin file will be loaded first, and then the init file directly after, which will contain the call to the plugin. This is confirmed when looking at the source. They are both appearing correctly in the head as `<script>` tags.

However, I'm getting the console error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'aToolTip' of null
(anonymous function) @ init.js:3
(anonymous function) @ init.js:7
```

The contents of my init.js file is like this:

```
((function(){
    // on click tooltip with custom content  
    $('a.clickTip').aToolTip({  
        clickIt: true,
        fixed: true
    });
})());
```

What's causing the console errors, and why aren't the files loading properly, even though they seem to be picked up correctly, and in order?

Answer (score 0):

It seems as though that the error is complaining that there are no 'a.clickTip' elements on the page. That is no  elements with a class attribute of clickTip?

Can you see anchor elements with that class in the page?

Comment: Yes, I wrote them. It's not just this plugin that doesn't work, it's anything that has a library JS, and then an initiation JS file that calls it. Same behaviour. It loads both files in order in the `<head>`, but doesn't seem to know what to do with them. I don't get it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about those specific plugins, but according to the reported error I think you need to change your init.js like this:

```
jQuery("document").ready(function (){
    // on click tooltip with custom content  
    $('a.clickTip').aToolTip({  
        clickIt: true,
        fixed: true
    });
});
```

because currently you are trying to run it before the dom is loaded and thus attach the aToolTip method to an element which is not existant on the page yet.

Comment: I see! Okay I'll try this tomorrow morning and will let you know how that goes